# syntax differences between Python 2.6.1 and 2.7.3?

Tags: syntax, syntax-error

So I used the following code snippet as part of a larger project,

```
with open(file) as fin:
    rows = ( line.split() for line in fin )
    d = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
```

For a tab delimited input, `file`. And it works fine on my personal machine, but when I move it over to a shared computing cluster, it doesn't like the 3rd line, `d = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }`. I've been trying to figure out why.

The only thing I could come up with was a difference in versions of Python. I'm running 2.7.3 and the shared cluster runs 2.6.1, but that doesn't seem totally reasonable - did I miss something totally obvious? I appreciate any advice y'all have.

Here is the text of the error (in Python 2.6.1 on cluster),

```
File "Alphabet.py", line 22
  d = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Edited, text of error added

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dict comprehension is new in Python 2.7, see PEP 274 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

From that:

```
>>> dict([(i, chr(65+i)) for i in range(4)])
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
>>> {i : chr(65+i) for i in range(4)}
```

If you need compatibility with Python before 2.7, use the first version.

Comment: d'oh! You are totally right. I figured it would be something like that--I'm still quite noobish at this. Now it works just fine--thanks!